# Affdex JS SDK - Can't get callbacks from the camera detector

Tags: javascript, affdex-sdk

I've tried running the Javascript [sample code taken from jsfiddle](https://github.com/Affectiva/js-sdk-sample-apps) on my own machine and find that I don't get a callback from the detector that would attempt to connect to the camera.

I see the first message that the start button is clicked but don't get the second message about the webcam access being allowed or denied.  This code is pretty much the same as your jsfiddle which works for accessing my webcam.   When I run on localhost it seems like the detector never makes the call to the callbacks for onWebcamConnectSuccess/Failure

I'm not seeing any errors on the console and am running on localhost with a web server (Tomcat).

**Here is my HTML file that loads both the affdex sdk and my script code js/testaffectiva.js**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src = "js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

    <script src="https://download.affectiva.com/js/3.1/affdex.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src = "js/testaffectiva.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8" id="affdex_elements" style="width:680px;height:480px;"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div style="height:25em;">
                <strong>EMOTION TRACKING RESULTS</strong>
                <div id="results" style="word-wrap:break-word;"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <strong>DETECTOR LOG MSGS</strong>
            </div>
            <div id="logs"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="start" onclick="onStart()">Start</button>
        <button id="stop" onclick="onStop()">Stop</button>
        <button id="reset" onclick="onReset()">Reset</button>
        <h3>Affectiva JS SDK CameraDetector to track different emotions.</h3>
        <p>
            <strong>Instructions</strong>
            </br>
            Press the start button to start the detector.
            <br/> When a face is detected, the probabilities of the different emotions are written to the DOM.
            <br/> Press the stop button to end the detector.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**js/testaffectiva.js**

```
/**
 * Created by david on 10/6/2016.
 */

// SDK Needs to create video and canvas nodes in the DOM in order to function
// Here we are adding those nodes a predefined div.
var divRoot = $("#affdex_elements")[0];
var width = 640;
var height = 480;
var faceMode = affdex.FaceDetectorMode.LARGE_FACES;
//Construct a CameraDetector and specify the image width / height and face detector mode.
var detector = new affdex.CameraDetector(divRoot, width, height, faceMode);

//Enable detection of all Expressions, Emotions and Emojis classifiers.
detector.detectAllEmotions();
detector.detectAllExpressions();
detector.detectAllEmojis();
detector.detectAllAppearance();

//Add a callback to notify when the detector is initialized and ready for runing.
detector.addEventListener("onInitializeSuccess", function() {
    log('#logs', "The detector reports initialized");
    //Display canvas instead of video feed because we want to draw the feature points on it
    $("#face_video_canvas").css("display", "block");
    $("#face_video").css("display", "none");
});

function log(node_name, msg) {
    $(node_name).append("<span>" + msg + "</span><br />")
}

//function executes when Start button is pushed.
function onStart() {
    if (detector && !detector.isRunning) {
        $("#logs").html("");
        detector.start();
    }
    log('#logs', "Clicked the start button");
}

//function executes when the Stop button is pushed.
function onStop() {
    log('#logs', "Clicked the stop button");
    if (detector && detector.isRunning) {
        detector.removeEventListener();
        detector.stop();
    }
};

//function executes when the Reset button is pushed.
function onReset() {
    log('#logs', "Clicked the reset button");
    if (detector && detector.isRunning) {
        detector.reset();

        $('#results').html("");
    }
};

//Add a callback to notify when camera access is allowed
detector.addEventListener("onWebcamConnectSuccess", function() {
    log('#logs', "Webcam access allowed");
});

//Add a callback to notify when camera access is denied
detector.addEventListener("onWebcamConnectFailure", function() {
    log('#logs', "webcam denied");
    console.log("Webcam access denied");
});

//Add a callback to notify when detector is stopped
detector.addEventListener("onStopSuccess", function() {
    log('#logs', "The detector reports stopped");
    $("#results").html("");
});

//Add a callback to receive the results from processing an image.
//The faces object contains the list of the faces detected in an image.
//Faces object contains probabilities for all the different expressions, emotions and appearance metrics
detector.addEventListener("onImageResultsSuccess", function(faces, image, timestamp) {
    $('#results').html("");
    log('#results', "Timestamp: " + timestamp.toFixed(2));
    log('#results', "Number of faces found: " + faces.length);
    if (faces.length > 0) {
        log('#results', "Appearance: " + JSON.stringify(faces[0].appearance));
        log('#results', "Emotions: " + JSON.stringify(faces[0].emotions, function(key, val) {
                return val.toFixed ? Number(val.toFixed(0)) : val;
            }));
        log('#results', "Expressions: " + JSON.stringify(faces[0].expressions, function(key, val) {
                return val.toFixed ? Number(val.toFixed(0)) : val;
            }));
        log('#results', "Emoji: " + faces[0].emojis.dominantEmoji);
        drawFeaturePoints(image, faces[0].featurePoints);
    }
});

//Draw the detected facial feature points on the image
function drawFeaturePoints(img, featurePoints) {
    var contxt = $('#face_video_canvas')[0].getContext('2d');

    var hRatio = contxt.canvas.width / img.width;
    var vRatio = contxt.canvas.height / img.height;
    var ratio = Math.min(hRatio, vRatio);

    contxt.strokeStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    for (var id in featurePoints) {
        contxt.beginPath();
        contxt.arc(featurePoints[id].x,
            featurePoints[id].y, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        contxt.stroke();

    }
}
```

Comment: SDK uses adaptor.js to access the html5 apis. Are you seeing any errors in the network tab ? Also which browser are u using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `$("#affdex_elements")[0]` returns `undefined` and therefore `CameraDetector` fails to add the necessary elements in the DOM for it to work (canvas, video) and silently breaks.

So this line

```
var divRoot = $("#affdex_elements")[0];
```

Needs to be executed after the DOM content is loaded:

```
var detector = null;
$(document).ready(function(){
  // SDK Needs to create video and canvas nodes in the DOM in order to function
  // Here we are adding those nodes a predefined div.
  var divRoot = $("#affdex_elements")[0];
  var width = 640;
  var height = 480;
  var faceMode = affdex.FaceDetectorMode.LARGE_FACES;
  //Construct a CameraDetector and specify the image width / height and face detector mode.
  detector = new affdex.CameraDetector(divRoot, width, height, faceMode);

  //Enable detection of all Expressions, Emotions and Emojis classifiers.
  detector.detectAllEmotions();
  detector.detectAllExpressions();
  detector.detectAllEmojis();
  detector.detectAllAppearance();

  //Add a callback to notify when the detector is initialized and ready for runing.
  detector.addEventListener("onInitializeSuccess", function() {
    log('#logs', "The detector reports initialized");
    //Display canvas instead of video feed because we want to draw the feature points on it
    $("#face_video_canvas").css("display", "block");
    $("#face_video").css("display", "none");
  });

  //Add a callback to notify when camera access is allowed
  detector.addEventListener("onWebcamConnectSuccess", function() {
    log('#logs', "Webcam access allowed");
  });

  //Add a callback to notify when camera access is denied
  detector.addEventListener("onWebcamConnectFailure", function() {
    log('#logs', "webcam denied");
    console.log("Webcam access denied");
  });

  //Add a callback to notify when detector is stopped
  detector.addEventListener("onStopSuccess", function() {
    log('#logs', "The detector reports stopped");
    $("#results").html("");
  });

  //Add a callback to receive the results from processing an image.
  //The faces object contains the list of the faces detected in an image.
  //Faces object contains probabilities for all the different expressions, emotions and appearance metrics
  detector.addEventListener("onImageResultsSuccess", function(faces, image, timestamp) {
    $('#results').html("");
    log('#results', "Timestamp: " + timestamp.toFixed(2));
    log('#results', "Number of faces found: " + faces.length);
    if (faces.length > 0) {
      log('#results', "Appearance: " + JSON.stringify(faces[0].appearance));
      log('#results', "Emotions: " + JSON.stringify(faces[0].emotions, function(key, val) {
        return val.toFixed ? Number(val.toFixed(0)) : val;
      }));
      log('#results', "Expressions: " + JSON.stringify(faces[0].expressions, function(key, val) {
        return val.toFixed ? Number(val.toFixed(0)) : val;
      }));
      log('#results', "Emoji: " + faces[0].emojis.dominantEmoji);
      drawFeaturePoints(image, faces[0].featurePoints);
    }
  });

  //Draw the detected facial feature points on the image
  function drawFeaturePoints(img, featurePoints) {
    var contxt = $('#face_video_canvas')[0].getContext('2d');

    var hRatio = contxt.canvas.width / img.width;
    var vRatio = contxt.canvas.height / img.height;
    var ratio = Math.min(hRatio, vRatio);

    contxt.strokeStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    for (var id in featurePoints) {
      contxt.beginPath();
      contxt.arc(featurePoints[id].x,
        featurePoints[id].y, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      contxt.stroke();

    }
  }
});

function log(node_name, msg) {
  $(node_name).append("<span>" + msg + "</span><br />")
}

//function executes when Start button is pushed.
function onStart() {
  if (detector && !detector.isRunning) {
    $("#logs").html("");
    detector.start();
  }
  log('#logs', "Clicked the start button");
}

//function executes when the Stop button is pushed.
function onStop() {
  log('#logs', "Clicked the stop button");
  if (detector && detector.isRunning) {
    detector.removeEventListener();
    detector.stop();
  }
};

//function executes when the Reset button is pushed.
function onReset() {
  log('#logs', "Clicked the reset button");
  if (detector && detector.isRunning) {
    detector.reset();

    $('#results').html("");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am running this on a Windows 7 machine with Chrome browser and don't see errors in the console or network tabs.

Comment: The fix above does work.  Part of the reason for the code being incorrect is that it was taken directly from the Javascript window of the JSFiddle demo.  For some reason jsfiddle doesn't list some of the lines of code e.g.  'var detector = null;
$(document).ready(function(){
  // SDK Needs to create video and canvas nodes in the DOM in order to function
  // Here we are adding those nodes a predefined div.
  var divRoot = $("#affdex_elements")[0];'